# AppAi.de appears to violate sandbox policy

Tags: ios, sandbox

An app recently appeared in Apple's App Store: [AppAide](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appaide/id529890484?ls=1&mt=8)

It appears to violate the app sandbox policy.  It claims to run in the background and gather statistics on which apps the user is running on their iOS device.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this might be technically possible?

Comment: If it does break out of the sandbox that bug should be fixed. Otherwise, if it doesn't break the sandbox, it probably uses some other method for "trending" apps.  Perhaps it just tracks the changes in the top apps in the App Store (ala AppShopper) or is sent that data rather than looking at what you are actually using on your iOS device and sending that data to a third party.

Comment: I would **guess** that it is directly connected to some tracking service (not Google Analytics but likewise). I would be really surprised if it actually broke the sandbox.